# How to go to the next section line in TeXShop?

Tags: mac, editors, texshop

What is the keyboard shortcut to jump from to the next section or subsection in an outputted document?

Comment: There is no such command that I'm aware of, but you can command-click on any place in the preview document to take you to the corresponding place in the source. Is that what you want?

Comment: Close voters: why are you voting to close this question? Please comment otherwise your close votes aren't helping improve the question.